# JS in Angular 2+ affects only on one component instead of affecting per component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular 2+ apllication where it is possible to choose image and see how it looks in preview.. The problem is that I have 3 components in parent HTML which can do the same work and contain the same JS script which affects only on first component. Code is presented below. [Here is Gif which presents how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN25A.gif)

parent HTML:

```
<div class="form-inline">
                <app-advert-photo-element id="first" [photoNumber]="1"></app-advert-photo-element>
                <app-advert-photo-element id="second" [photoNumber]="2"></app-advert-photo-element>
                <app-advert-photo-element id="third" [photoNumber]="3"></app-advert-photo-element>
</div>
```

app-advert-photo-element HTML:

```
<div class="polaroid">
  <label for="photo" class="cursor-pointer">
    <img [src]="url" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </label>
  <div class="img-title-bot">
    Nr {{photoNumber}}.
  </div>
  <input type="file" id="photo" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
</div>
```

app-advert-photo-element.ts:

```
export class AdvertPhotoElementComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  protected photoNumber;

  protected url = '';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelectFile(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (onLoadEvent: any) => {
        this.url = onLoadEvent.target.result;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me. I cannot find a solution...
Reproduced: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4df6q

As I can see the problem is in CSS.. without my CSS it works correctly

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on this stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-naw1nu

Comment: @AlexK I have added some CSS to AdvertPhotoElementComponent. Thank you for attention. Link is added in main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I see the issue.

Each of your component instances renders `<input id="photo">`. Because each input has the same id "photo", the `<label for="photo">` refers only to the first input with that id.

Here's a demo of what's happening. Try clicking each label and see which input gets focused:

```html
<div>
  <label for="input">Label for #input</label>
  <input id="input" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="input">Label for #input</label>
  <input id="input" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="input1">Label for #input1</label>
  <input id="input1" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="input2">Label for #input 2</label>
  <input id="input2" />
</div>
```

To fix this, give each input a unique id, and pass that same id to the corresponding label:

```
<div class="polaroid">
  <label for="photo{{photoNumber}}" class="cursor-pointer">
    <img [src]="url" class="img-fluid" alt="">
  </label>
  <div class="img-title-bot">
    Nr {{photoNumber}}.
  </div>
  <input type="file" id="photo{{photoNumber}}" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
</div>
```